# Windows Server 2022, Storage Pool physical disks show up in Disk Manager, missing in pool

Tags: storage-spaces, windows-server-2022, storage-pool

I have a WS2022 with a storage pool of six drives. Recently drives have been missing from the pool "Lost communication" and show up as drives with a Storage Spaces Protective Partition in Disk Manager.
[image]

At the same time, disk 7 in this example is missing from my pool:
[image]

How can I make sure pooled disks are not detected in Disk Manager?
It would seem that this is a Storage Spaces driver problem.

Comment: This is a professional site. Problems can be frustrating, but please focus on professional language on this site.

Comment: This sounds like failing disks. "Lost communication" and Protective Partition Manager are functions that SSD uses to protect data on failing drives. This looks like SSD working properly. Test your drives: it is likely this will indicate the source of this problem.

Comment: @music2myear My apologies for language. 
Depending on how I attach the disks, different disks lose connection. All disks seem ok, but there is always one or two disks that are marked as Lost connection. The disks are in USB enclosures - one 8-bay, one 2-bay and one 1-bay. I shut down, move the disks around, start up, and different disks are not connected. There is no pattern WRT disks, no pattern WRT enclosure or slot in enclosure.
I even moved the storage pool to connect to a laptop running Windows 11, got the same behavior there.

Comment: Have you tested each of the disks individually then? As they are connected via USB, are they running through the same USB controller or different controllers? Does which controller they're connected through impact which ones are not working? What are the brand/model of the enclosures?